# elasticsearch flushrequest.full() depricated between 1.3.2 and 1.7

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm upgrading some java code which builds an elasticsearch index from elasticsearch 1.3.2 to 1.7 and to spring-data-elasticsearch 1.2.1.RELEASE.

All is well except for my class destroy function

```
client.admin().indices().flush(new FlushRequest(INDEX_NAME).full(true));
```

now fails.  full() is no longer a valid method.

I'm guessing this is a default option now and I can get away with

```
client.admin().indices().flush(new FlushRequest(INDEX_NAME));
```

but I'm struggling to find definitive documentation.

Could anyone tell me!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be the case somewhat.  At least it seems they felt it was not necessary.  Here is a link to the change.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/45dc3ef705676771e250fdafae5098a6cab9dc11

Comment: Wish they documented the API better.